# Retrieving row and column number from within a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying retrieve row and column number for following strings. The numbers that follow the R are the row no and numbers that follow the C are column numbers. Also as you can see some of them are 4 digits and some of them are 3 digits. How do I use a single function to retrieve the row and column number respectively.

```
NSFR80R0020C0030   e.g Row is 0020  Column is  0030
C75.01R2220C050    e.g Row is 2220  Column is  050 
C76R380C010        e.g Row is  380  Column is  010
```

I started by using the patindex but not sure how to determine based on it. Could somebody help

```
 SELECT PATINDEX('%R%C%','C75.01R2220C050')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, be very clear about the string format (which seems to contain additional information).  Desired results help.

Comment: I have tagged thank you

Comment: Be more specific about your logic. Row number is BETWEEN R and C? Column follows C to end of string? Always? No exceptions to your string formats? Don't guess. Don't assume. Don't just look at some small sample of rows.

Comment: Which SQL Server version do you use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This forum isn't for solving your programming tasks. But for the fun of it, I've done it for the row number:

```
create FUNCTION getRow 
(
    @s varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(4)
    declare @ind int

    SET @ind = PATINDEX('%R[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @s)
    if @ind > 0
        set @Result = SUBSTRING(@s, @ind + 1, 4)
    else begin
        SET @ind = PATINDEX('%R[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @s)
        if @ind > 0
            set @Result = SUBSTRING(@s, @ind + 1, 3)
        else
            set @Result = ''
    end

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `parsename()` in concert with a  `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('NSFR80R0020C0030')
,('C75.01R2220C050')
,('C76R380C010')
 
Select SomeCol
      ,Row = parsename(rS,2)
      ,Col = parsename(rS,1)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (replace(right(SomeCol,charindex('R',reverse(SomeCol))-1),'C','.'))) B(rS)
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol             Row     Col
NSFR80R0020C0030    0020    0030
C75.01R2220C050     2220    050
C76R380C010         380     010
```